# Objective-C completion in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to translate this in swift:

```
[NetworkManager pauseSubscription:info
                         completion:^BOOL(NetworkResponseStatus status, UserData *response) {
                             BOOL used = NO;
                             if (status == NetworkResponseStatusSuccess) {
                                 used = YES;
                                 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                             }
                             return used;
                         }];
```

I tried this but I got: '(NetworkResponseStatus, UserData) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'UserDataCompletionBlock!'

```
 NetworkManager.pauseSubscription(info, completion: {
        (status: NetworkResponseStatus, response:UserData) -> Bool in
        var used = false
        if status == NetworkResponseStatus.success {
            used = true
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        return used

    })
```

How can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Types don't match. `NetworkResponseStatus` is same type as `MCNetworkResponseStatus`?

Comment: how is `UserDataCompletionBlock` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift do not annotate the types in the completion closure. The syntax is supposed to be (including trailing closure syntax and an underscore for unused `response` parameter):

```
NetworkManager.pauseSubscription(info) { (status, _) -> Bool in
    var used = false
    if status == .success {
        used = true
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    return used

}
```

or *swiftier*

```
NetworkManager.pauseSubscription(info) { (status, _) -> Bool in
    switch status {
      case .success 
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
      default: return false
    }
}
```